# I want to count how many questions are attended by user

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to count how many question are user attended. If user click any one options from one question I want to increment one value. Ex: if user attend 7/10 the count will be 7.

```
<div id="ques1" class="showquestion">
    <div class="ques">
        <p>Questions ////////////</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        A)
        <input id="op-1-0" name="answers19" value="2918" type="radio" />
    </div>
    <div>
        B)
        <input id="op-1-1" name="answers19" value="2919" type="radio" />
    </div>
    <div>
        C)
        <input id="op-1-2" name="answers19" value="2920" type="radio" />
    </div>
    <div>
        B)
        <input id="op-1-3" name="answers19" value="2921" type="radio" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="ques2" class="showquestion">
    <div class="ques">
        <p>Questions ////////////</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        A)
        <input id="op-1-0" name="answers19" value="2918" type="radio" />
    </div>
    <div>
        B)
        <input id="op-1-1" name="answers19" value="2919" type="radio" />
    </div>
    <div>
        C)
        <input id="op-1-2" name="answers19" value="2920" type="radio" />
    </div>
    <div>
        B)
        <input id="op-1-3" name="answers19" value="2921" type="radio" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="button-group">
    <input value="Previous" type="button" />
    <input value="Next" type="button" />
</div>
<br/>
<div id="count"></div>
```

Comment: in css you may do something like this : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/mshLl it lets have the count before it is sent to server. it is only visual and is not recorded anywhere

Answer (score 0):

here is your answer: (jquery)

```
  var total = $(':radio:checked').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one..

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/smkavin/hkputruh/3/)

```
$('#click').click(function(){
var total = $(':radio:checked').length;
alert(total);
});
```

clcik next and check it in jsfiddle demo.

Comment: Its worked well. I have one question how to make this function on user clicks any one of radio(options).